# How do I show that a holomorphic function which satisfies this bound on reciprocals of integers is identically zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I'm trying to show that $f$ is a holomorphic (around the origin) map satisfying $|f(\frac{1}{n})|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}\forall n\in\mathbb N$ then $f$ is identically zero. Usually, if some function equals an analytic function on a dense set, we can invoke uniqueness of analytic continuation. But in this case, we don't have equality, just a bound. I tried Cauchy's integral formula also, but to no avail. How do I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is the function f entire?

Comment: An idea, if $f$ is holomorphic near the origin, then $f$ is analytic near $0$ and one has for any fixed $p$ $f(1/n)=a_0+a_1 /n+ \cdots +a_p / n^p+o(1 / n^p)$ but one deduces $\left|2^n f(1/n)\right| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ which contradicts $|f(1/n)|\leq 1/2^n \:\forall n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it's not immediately clear to me why the limit should be infinity. We don't know anything about the coefficients of the power series.

Comment: @adrija the coefficients must be bounded by the given condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is not identically zero there is a $p\geq0$ and an analytic function $z\mapsto g(z)$ with $g(0)=:c\ne0$ such that
$$f(z)=z^p g(z)\qquad\bigl(z\in U(0)\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that
$$2^n f\left({1\over n}\right)={2^n\over n^p}\>g\left({1\over n}\right)\to\infty\qquad(n\to\infty)\ ,$$
contrary to assumption.

Comment: are you invoking schwarz lemma in your first assumption?