# Could anyone please give me some hints?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in the disc $D_2(0)$ and the absolute value of $f\left(\frac1n\right)$ is less than $\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all positive integers $n$. Show that $f$ is identically zero in the aforementioned disc.

Comment: The subject should indicate what the problem is. E.g. Analytic $f(n) < 1/2^n$ is identically zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show that a holomorphic function which satisfies this bound on reciprocals of integers is identically zero?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031222/how-do-i-show-that-a-holomorphic-function-which-satisfies-this-bound-on-reciproc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from continuity, f(0)=0.Suppose f is not constant. Let N be the order of zero at z=0. Then f=gz^N for some holomorphic function g such that g(0) is not zero. We have a contradiction after we plug g in the inequality because it implies g(0) should be zero.